# Understanding Illumina Adapters

Tags: rna-sequencing

I am currently working on a project where I need to trim the adapters off of some single end read RNA-Seq data, and I want to know which sequences to cleave.  Illumina TruSeq [adapters](https://support.illumina.com/content/dam/illumina-support/documents/documentation/chemistry_documentation/experiment-design/illumina-customer-sequence-letter.pdf) were used.  I have tried following Tuft's [explanation](http://tucf-genomics.tufts.edu/documents/protocols/TUCF_Understanding_Illumina_TruSeq_Adapters.pdf) and make sense of Illumina's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMyCqWhwB8E), but I am left with several unresolved questions.

The TruSeq Universal adapter, seems to be what binds to the flow cell and is

```
AATGATACGGCGACCACCGAGATCTACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCT
```

The TruSeq Adapter Index N is

```
 GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCAC-NNNNNN-ATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG
```

My impression of how the cDNA fragment attached to the adapters is :

```
(flow cell)
||
||
||                                             (Index Adapter)                                               (Universal Adapter)
||    3'                                                                5'                          3'                                                        5'  
||    GTTCGTCTTCTGCCGTATGCTCTA-NNNNNN-CACTGACCTCAAGTCTGCACACGAGAAGGCTAGA                           TCTAGCCTTCTCGCAGCACATCCCTTTCTCACATCTAGAGCCACCAGCGGCATAGTAA
||                                                         ||||||||||||||                           ||||||||||||||                                                              <----- Must get denatured!
||        5'   AATGATCGGCGACCACCGAGATCTACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCT--(5' MY DNA FRAGMENT 3')--AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCAC‐NNNNNN‐ATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG
||-------------TTACTAGCCGCTGGTGGCT                                     3'                           5'                                                                3'  
||    
||             ^(Flow cell oligo)              ^(Universal Adapter)                                            ^(Index Adapter)
||  
||                                     TGTGAGAAAGGGATGTGCTGCGAGAAGGCTAGA                           TCTAGCCTTCTCGTGTGCAGACTTGAGGTCAGTGTG
||    
||                                             ^(Read 1 Primer)                                                ^(Read 2 Primer)
||
||    
||                                                                                                                                           TAGAGCATACGGCAGAAGACGAAC----------||
||    
||                                                                                                                                               ^(Flow cell oligo)
||
```

Here are my questions :

1. Is this image correct in the single stranded case?
2. Do I have the correct primer binding site (used for the actual sequencing)?
3. Do I have the correct oligo for paired end reads, i.e. `TAGAGCATACGGCAGAAGACGAAC---------`?
4. Do I have the correct primer (and it's site) for the index read?

<sup><sub>Per Illumina, I guess I need to include this : 
"Oligonucleotide sequences © 2007-2013 Illumina, Inc. All rights reserved. Derivative
works created by Illumina customers are authorized for use with Illumina instruments
and products only. All other uses are strictly prohibited."</sub></sup>